# How do you clear a <div>s contents with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<div id="editform"></div>`. I have certain html currently in it. How do I clear that html and insert completely different html in it?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Title\" id=\"title\" name=\"title\" style=\"display: 

block;\"><textarea rows=\"10\" style=\"display: block;\" id=\"textLoc\" placeholder=\"Text to test\"cols=\"50\"></textarea>";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need to escape " in the string, you can use ' inside the html string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, as long as you remove (or escape) the line breaks from the new HTML string.

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/olabo4/

So change this:

```
document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Title\" id=\"title\" name=\"title\" style=\"display: 

block;\"><textarea rows=\"10\" style=\"display: block;\" id=\"textLoc\" placeholder=\"Text to test\"cols=\"50\"></textarea>";
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Title\" id=\"title\" name=\"title\" style=\"display: block;\"><textarea rows=\"10\" style=\"display: block;\" id=\"textLoc\" placeholder=\"Text to test\"cols=\"50\"></textarea>";
```

or this:

```
document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Title\" id=\"title\" name=\"title\" style=\"display: \
\
block;\"><textarea rows=\"10\" style=\"display: block;\" id=\"textLoc\" placeholder=\"Text to test\"cols=\"50\"></textarea>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var cell = document.getElementById("cell");

if ( cell.hasChildNodes() )
{
    while ( cell.childNodes.length >= 1 )
    {
        cell.removeChild( cell.firstChild );       
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adding HTML to the div using `document.createNode(...)` and `document.appendChild(...)`, instead of adding it as innerHTML. Altering innerHTML tends to be buggy.

Comment: This is not necessarily true, there are just different things to remember when using `innerHTML`.  Both ways work the same.

Comment: Well, when you add innerHTML to an element, all the event listeners of child elements will be removed. That's really the only one I've encountered.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean. Since you have to re-assign all of the methods and properties of the children anyway, oftentimes I find `innerHTML` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

That should work...maybe the problem is somewhere else?

If you want to remove all of the child nodes, try this:

```
function removeChildren(obj) {
  while(obj.hasChildNodes()) { obj.removeChild(obj.lastChild); }
};
```

Call it like this:

`removeChildren(document.getElementById('editform'))`;

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "";
```

This should work.

and btw, you don't need to escape " in the string, you can use ' inside the string.

Also, to make your life easier, I would recommend some javascript library like JQuery or Mootools, so that your DOM manipulation is easier and cross browser compatible.

Comment: yeah, I am planning to change that but isn't it cross-browser compatible in most cases when it is relatively basic?